# Confusion regarding proof of cosine law by vector method

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, vectors

The proof of cosine law is simple: if $A$, $B$ and $C$ are three vectors then we take $C = A-B$, then,
$$|C|^2 = (A-B)\cdot(A-B).$$
From this it naturally follows. But what if we take $C = A+B$? It still is a valid triangle. But, then the cosine formula is wrong.

I want to understand why it is not true for $C=A+B$ and true for $C = A-B$.

Comment: This would be set up with A and B both being position vectors or displacements from the origin, and the origin would be the point C. If vector C goes from point A to point B then displacement vector C = B - A, where B and A are the position vectors of the points B and C. More generally the displacement vector from start point to end point is end vector minus start vector.

Comment: If $\theta$ is the angle opposite to $C$ when $C=A-B$, then $\pi-\theta$ is the angle opposite to $C$ when $C=A+B$. And $\cos(\pi-\theta)=-\cos\theta$.